# Showing that $x^2−x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that $x^2−x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I am new to this so sorry if this question is really low level.

My understanding so far is that to simply use the quadratic formula which shows that the roots have $i$ in them, and hence they are not in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the polynomial is irreducible. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah I think that works ! the only possible factors would be of degree one so a rational root would have to exist.

Comment: If $ F$  is a field, $f(x)\in F[x]  $ is reducible if and only if $f(x) $ has a zero in $F$, but this is only always true for polynomials of degree $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the math in your questions.

Comment: Also from the same page:  "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $x^2-x+1$ reducible over $\mathbb Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438198/is-x2-x1-reducible-over-mathbb-q)

Comment: @MarkBennet The question is closed without an answer, what’s the point of linking to it?

Comment: You should edit your previous question, which is essentially the same, rather than reposting essentially the same question as has already been closed.

Comment: @GarethMa I had forgotten that marking duplicates worked like that, but it is the same question asked by the same person and should be edited rather than reposted.

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh didn’t realise its the same person, my bad

Comment: By the way, now that this duplicate of the original question has been closed, and the original question itself has been edited to add some context, it would be reasonable to vote to re-open the original question itself and answer it there.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, but just because the degree of your polynomial is less than $4$. That is because if you have a reducible polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$, then it will be the product of two polynomials of lower degree, and one of them will be of degree $1$ and you will have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$. But, for example, the polynomial $x^4+2x^2+1$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$, but it is not irreducible since $x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2$.

Comment: The polynomial $x^2-1$ has degree less than four and clearly two roots in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Of course. What I said is that the argument: "the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ because it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$" is only valid if the polynomial has degree less than $4$. The reason is what I said above.